# Intermodule optimization during compilation

Tags: performance, optimization, compilation

It is obvious that given any large codebase separate compilation of modules can significantly cut down compilation time. Still, I wonder if it worth to compile a production release in a single step, considering that the longer the code the more optimization can take place across. Is this presumption right?

The question is not language or tool specific but I’m particularly interested in C++ and GCC.

Comment: Questions about the release process, as opposed to specific code, belong on programmers.se.  Also, some information about what language and tools you're using might get you better answers.

Comment: The question is very language and tool specific.  Most Java runtimes, for example, perform optimization at load time, rather than runtime, so they already optimize across module boundaries.

Comment: It is very welcome to share experiences regarding any platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. In fact, it's a compilation strategy that's used by almost any modern compiler out there.

You may want to look up [IPO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) and [LTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-time_optimization).